# Can't bind to property since it isn't a known property of 'component' in Angular

Tags: angular

I am building a share component in Angular 7. The shared component is modal window. It works fine when I used the shared component within a specific module but it gives me an error if I add the shared component to the shared module. As you can see in the code , I have created an shared module which exports the shared component. I have added that to the declarations of the AppModule. I have then imported it to another module where I need to use the modal window for one of its components.

What am i missing ?

error

```
Can't bind to 'modalSize' since it isn't a known property of 'shared-modal'.
1. If 'shared-modal' is an Angular component and it has 'modalSize' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'shared-modal' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
```

AppModule

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { StrategyService } from './services/strategy.service';
import { ManagerService } from './services/manager.service';
import { InteractionService } from './services/interaction.service';
import { DocumentService } from './services/document.service';
import { CommonDataService } from './services/common.data.service';
import { Comparator } from './utilities/comparator';
import { Formatter } from './utilities/formatter';
import { FileUpload } from './utilities/fileUpload';
import { WindowRef } from './utilities/window.ref';
import { NotifyService } from './utilities/notify.service';
import { LayoutModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-layout';
import { DateInputsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs';
import { DropDownsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns';
import { InputsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-inputs';
import { TreeViewModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-treeview';
import { CKEditorModule } from '../custom/ng2-ckeditor';
import { BsModalModule } from 'ng2-bs3-modal';
import { AngularFileUploaderModule } from 'angular-file-uploader';
import { AppConfig } from './app.config';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule, routedComponents } from './app.routing';
import { SharedModule} from './shared/shared.module';
import { ManagerStrategyModule } from './manager-strategy/managerStrategy.module';
import { HomeModule } from './home/home.module';
import { AngularFontAwesomeModule } from 'angular-font-awesome';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        DateInputsModule,
        DropDownsModule,
        CKEditorModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        BsModalModule,
        LayoutModule,
        AngularFileUploaderModule,
        InputsModule,
        TreeViewModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        SharedModule,
        ManagerStrategyModule,
        HomeModule,
        AngularFontAwesomeModule
    ],
     exports: [
     ],

    providers: [
        StrategyService,
        ManagerService,
        InteractionService,
        DocumentService,
        CommonDataService,
        NotifyService,
        AppConfig,
        Comparator,
        Formatter,
        WindowRef,
        FileUpload
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

shared module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { SharedModal } from '../shared/shared-modal';


@NgModule ({
    imports: [CommonModule
            , FormsModule],
    declarations: [SharedModal],
    exports: [SharedModal],
    providers: []
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

shared modal ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, SimpleChange, SimpleChanges, DoCheck } from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any;
@Component({
    selector: 'shared-modal',
    templateUrl: './shared-modal.html'
})
export class SharedModal {
    _isopen = false;
    @Input()
    private _modalSize = 1; // 1:normal, 2: medium, 3: large
    public get modalSize() {
        return this._modalSize;
    }
    public set modalSize(value) {
        this._modalSize = value;
    }

    get open(): boolean {
        return this._isopen;
    }

    @Input()
    set open(val: boolean) {
        this._isopen = val;
    }
    getModalDialogClass() {
        if (this.modalSize == null || this.modalSize <= 1 || this.modalSize > 3) {
            return 'modal-dialog';
        } else if (this.modalSize <= 2) {
            return 'modal-dialog modal-md';
        } else if (this.modalSize <= 3) {
            return 'modal-dialog modal-lg';
        }
    }
}
```

shared modal html

```
<div id="modal_container">
        <div id="shared_modal" class="modal fade show" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" role="dialog" [ngStyle]="{'display': _isopen ? 'block' : 'none','z-index':'1050' }">
            <div [ngClass] = "getModalDialogClass()">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <ng-content select=[header]></ng-content>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <ng-content select=[body]></ng-content>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <ng-content select=[footer]></ng-content>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-backdrop fade show" *ngIf="_isopen" style="display: block; z-index: 1040;"></div>
        <div class="modal-backdrop fade show" *ngIf="!_isopen" style="display: none; z-index: 1040;"></div>
    </div>
```

other module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular/main';
import { CKEditorModule } from '../../custom/ng2-ckeditor';
import { DateInputsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs';
import { TabStripModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-layout';
import { DropDownsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns';
import { SharedModule} from '../shared/shared.module';
import { ManagerStrategyComponent } from './managerStrategy.component';
import { ManagerStrategyDetailsComponent } from './strategyDetails.component';
import { FirmComponent } from '../firm/firm.component';
import { FundComponent } from '../fund/fund.component';
import { ManagerComponent } from '../manager/manager.component';
import { AllocationsComponent } from '../allocations/allocations.component';
import { PeerGroupComponent } from '../peer-group/peergroup.component';
import { ClassificationOverridesComponent } from '../classification-overrides/classificationoverrides.component';
import { FundStatisticsComponent } from './fundStatistics.component';
import { FundTermsComponent } from '../fund-terms/fundterms.component';
import { ManagerStrategyPerformaceComponent } from './strategyPerformance.component'
import { TabContentLoadOnDemandDirective } from './lazyload.directive';
import { BsModalModule } from 'ng2-bs3-modal';
//import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
// import {NgbdModalComponent, NgbdModalContent} from '../shared/modal-component';


@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ManagerStrategyComponent,
        ManagerStrategyDetailsComponent,
        FundStatisticsComponent,
        ManagerStrategyPerformaceComponent,
        TabContentLoadOnDemandDirective,
        FirmComponent,
        FundComponent,
        ManagerComponent,
        AllocationsComponent,
        PeerGroupComponent,
        ClassificationOverridesComponent,
        FundTermsComponent
        // NgbdModalComponent,
        // NgbdModalContent
    ],
    // entryComponents: [NgbdModalContent],
    imports: [
        FormsModule,
        BrowserModule,
        DateInputsModule,
        AgGridModule,
        CKEditorModule,
        TabStripModule,
        BsModalModule,
        DropDownsModule,
        SharedModule
        // NgbModule.forRoot()
    ],
    exports: [
        ManagerStrategyComponent,
        ManagerStrategyDetailsComponent,
        FundStatisticsComponent,
        ManagerStrategyPerformaceComponent,
        FirmComponent,
        FundComponent,
        ManagerComponent,
        AllocationsComponent,
        PeerGroupComponent,
        ClassificationOverridesComponent,
        DropDownsModule

    ]
})

export class ManagerStrategyModule { }
```

other module's component html

```
<div>
      <shared-modal [modalSize]="3" class="survey-edit" [open]="managerWindowOpened">
            <div style="width: 100%;" header>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Manager - {{ManagerStrategyDetails.ManagerName}}
                    <div style="text-align: right"><button aria-label="Dismiss" class="close" style="margin-top: -20px"
                            type="button" (click)="dismissManagerModal()">X</button></div>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div body>
                <mgr-manager [ManagerId]='ManagerId'></mgr-manager>

            </div>
            <div footer>
            </div>
        </shared-modal>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The @Input annotation should be placed on the setter of the _moduleSize, directly:

```
private _modalSize = 1; // 1:normal, 2: medium, 3: large
public get modalSize() {
    return this._modalSize;
}
@Input()
public set modalSize(value) {
    this._modalSize = value;
}
```

Previously, the annotation declared only the private parameter as the input. But, since it is private, it's not visible. Placing it on the public setter, will allow you to properly use it in other places.